# overlapping axes in python plotly parallel coordinates plot

Tags: python, plotly

How should I modify the code add traces without overlapping the axes in python Plotly parallel coordinates plot.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

angular_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
cluster_rep_arr = np.random.rand(3, 5)

trace_list = []
figure = go.Figure()
for i, data in enumerate(cluster_rep_arr):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(1, 5), columns=angular_labels)
    df['sample'] = i
    x = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color='sample', color_continuous_scale="picnic", dimensions=df.columns[:-1])
    figure.add_trace(x.data[0])
figure.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are mixing px and go.Figure(), which seems to be causing some conflicts here
2. You are creating multiple instances of the graph (each with its own axes) and displaying them within one Figure are, causing the overlapping axes with different scaling
3. This is how I would do it in px: create one dataframe before plotting. For go.Figure see https://plotly.com/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/

   ```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    angular_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    cluster_rep_arr = np.random.rand(3, 5)

    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(1, 5), columns=angular_labels) for i, data in enumerate(cluster_rep_arr)])
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    df['sample'] = df.index

    print(df)

    fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color='sample', color_continuous_scale="picnic", dimensions=df.columns[:-1])                  
    fig.show()
   ```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I want a trace added sequentially in each loop iteration. I also implemented like what you did finally. by using an array to append individal data point and then after the loop ends plot them together in a single parcoords plot.